# Ionic emulate android --livereload don't take the changes

Tags: ionic-framework, livereload

[image: i have compiled successfully in the console but i can't see changes in the emulator]

i have compiled successfully in the console but i can't see changes in the emulator

Comment: did you try? ionic capacitor run android -l --external 

for more info: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/livereload

Answer (score 0):

eventually this entry helps:

1. Open android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xm
2. Add this to your AndroidManifest.xml in the tag (Tag application already exists)

   "< application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" >"

Sometimes the livereload doesn't work because of an error which exists. Then first correct the errors. Also you can try to create an empty source.ts file and save it. After this he should recompile...

Comment: this already exist :
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.instabug.cordova.plugin.MyApplication" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

Comment: the livereloads run for you ?

Comment: I can't see any of these problem in my installation. Restart the emulator in android studio or add an new virtual device. Maybe it solves the problem.

Comment: i can run the application in an emulator, but I need the livereload, I can't build each time I edit my code it take much time

Comment: see additional infos above